# pdf to mobi convertor

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, conversion, ebooks, mobi

Is there any application which can convert a `.pdf` file into a `.mobi` file?

Comment: the only interest of converting a pdf to mobi would be in keeping the formatting and images in the mobi format: this is not possible (at least not in Calibre, and there are no better ways). to have a readable and easily editable file without original formating,convert pdf to text, and maybe then, if desired , to mobi (but there's no supplementary advantage there).. to keep all formatting, images etc, try to read pdf on the ebook reader

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try http://calibre-ebook.com/ I'm not sure how well it works for Linux but on Windows it is the perfect solution for managing your eBook library and obviously also converting from anything

Comment: not all pdf can be converted properly into mobi using Calibre, in which case try to convert to text, and then to mobi in Calibre

Answer (score 35):

Once you have installed the calibre package, you can use the GUI, but if you want to script it, there is also a command line converter installed as part of the calibre package - `ebook-convert` ([docs](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/ebook-convert.html)). The simplest way to call it would be:

```
ebook-convert document.pdf .mobi
```

which will convert the pdf into MOBI format with the same name. That should "just work" but if you want to go deeper then see the [detailed documentation on conversion](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/conversion.html).

Note that Calibre [supports lots of formats](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#what-formats-does-calibre-support-conversion-to-from), not just MOBI, for both input and output.

Comment: I would note this appears to convert to HTML first, then to pdf from that.  You may want to adjust the pdf first using k2pdfopt then convert to .mobi

Comment: btw, I've managed to extract ebook-convert from calibre (to avoid having to install Qt/X11 dependencies) and be able to run it on a headless/server machine: https://askubuntu.com/a/1453851/182054

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it online... Although it is not always recommendable to convert PDFs to Mobi since the formats are quite different.

http://www.mobi-to-pdf.com/

Comment: This site displays ads, invokes trackers, and never returns a completed conversion.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert online pdf files to mobi / epub with the following conversion tool kit webpage:

http://kitpdf.com/