# Is there a way to convert a PDF file to ePUB format WITHOUT using Calibre

Tags: pdf, ebooks, epub

I'll tell you clearly and loudly: I don't like Calibre!
So, how can I convert PDF to ePUB without it?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

We know you don't like Calibre... but have you tried its CLI conversion tool?

The Calibre install provides the command `ebook-convert` that will handle what you want, and there's no need to run Calibre.

```
ebook-convert file.pdf file.epub
```

is all that's required.

If the output looks a little wrong - try this

```
ebook-convert file.pdf file.epub --enable-heuristics
```

It will try a "smart" way to convert. Not perfect, but can work well in most conversions.

Comment: Any way to make it work with 2 column documents?  The `--enable-heuristics` flag does not work well with those.

Comment: According to their website, multi-column PDFs are not supported.

Comment: Wow thanks. For multiple PDF files within a folder I used this after `cd`ing to the directory: `find ./ -iname "*pdf" -type f | while read f; do echo -e "\e[1mConverting file $f \e[0m" ; ebook-convert "$f" "${f%.pdf}.epub" --enable-heuristics ; done
`

Comment: @DracNoc what about windows machine?

Comment: note that if you don't have the ebook-convert command, you may have installed calibre through flatpak or snap. Uninstall your existing calibre through the software center, or flatpak remove, or snap remove and then install with apt

Comment: @PrashantTapase - I don't see why you should have any trouble. The GUI offers the same options as the CLI. The GUI has more of a per-device set of rules. You can opt on how files are converted when they are transferred according to what reader you plugged in. A Kobo reader uses epub, Kindle has mobi. Calibre should pick that up automatically, but you can always use the convert icon to fine tune what you have in your library.

Comment: Well the Calibre converter is just crap in general. In a PDF where the text appearance is images, but the text itself is actually also stored, Calibre (and ebook-convert) will discard the text entirely and store shitty downscaled versions of the image pages instead.

Answer (score 14):

LibreOffice has an epub exporter [extension](http://lukesblog.it/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page), so you can install the LibreOffice PDF importer extension, import your PDF, and then export to epub.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [www.convertfiles.com](http://www.convertfiles.com/), you can easily convert `.pdf` to `.epub` using their free online conversion tool.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but for people who want to read PDFs on an e-reader and are finding it cumbersome, one solution may be to crop the margins of the PDF, and read in landscape mode. That works acceptably well for me on my e-reader in any case. There are many PDF croppers out there. Just search for "pdf crop" or "pdf trim".

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to cut out `ebook-convert` from Calibre (which, for who knows what reasons, requires `Qt` for image manipulation) and got a command-line only interface for it, to be able to use the tool on a headless/server machine.

The steps involved extracting these directories from the `calibre` package (deb, rpm, whatever):

```
/usr/bin/ebook-convert
/usr/lib/calibre
/usr/share/calibre
```

Installing some missing python modules (which you figure out by running the convert command `ebook-convert inputfile outputfile`), in my case:

```
python3-msgpack
python3-dateutil
python3-lxml
python3-css-parser
python3-pil
```

etc.

I also had to specify a command line option [`--mobi-keep-original-images`](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/ebook-convert.html#cmdoption-ebook-convert-mobi-output-mobi-keep-original-images), since I wanted to convert `epub` to `mobi` format using: `ebook-convert ~/test.epub ~/test.mobi --mobi-keep-original-images`

The last part was the most painful, since it involved modifying some of the python util scripts, which use `Qt` (which then requires some X11 libs) for image manipulation and we want to avoid that on a server/headless machine. Basically, I removed Qt imports and fixed the remaining errors in the scripts by making those functions empty (or throw an exception) in these 2 files (in my case):

```
/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/utils/img.py
/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/ebooks/conversion/plugins/mobi_output.py
```

In short, the conversion tool only uses `Qt` for image manipulation operations. If you can live with unmodified images from the original book that you are converting and don't need to compress/resize those images, then you're lucky, since you can avoid using Qt/X11.

Note to `calibre` developers: Why did you not use standard image manipulation libraries? Why choose a heavy GUI-oriented framework (like Qt) for simple image operations? Quite a great package (calibre) with such a poor decision, in my opinion...

Answer (score 0):

[2epub.com](http://2epub.com) - the same online converter with  batch processing and output compression files