# How to add page numbers to output when converting epub file via command line interface of ebook-convert (calibre)?

Tags: command-line, pdf, ebooks, calibre

I have an epub file and want to convert it into a PDF file.

I am using `ebook-convert` as suggested in [converting epub files to PDF format](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299747/converting-epub-files-to-pdf-format) (version: `ebook-convert (calibre 3.21.0)`)

**I am looking for a parameter to set page numbers in the output pdf file.**

Using the help function only states to use recipes:

```
--list-recipes  List builtin recipe names. You can create an e-book from a
              builtin recipe like this: ebook-convert "Recipe Name.recipe"
              output.epub
```

Looking at these recipes via the cli, I can find over 1600 recipes available on my computer.

But from this I do not know which is the right recipe that automatically generates page numbers in the PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the parameters for a specific format, type:

`ebook-convert myfile.input_format myfile.output_format -h`

To add page numbers, simply type:

`ebook-convert myfile.epub myfile.pdf --pdf-page-numbers`