# How can I convert this epub file to pdf?

Tags: pdf, convert, calibre, epub, pandoc

I have tried Calibre to convert an epub file to pdf, following https://askubuntu.com/a/299752/

```
ebook-convert /tmp/1.epub 1.pdf
```

but it fails with many errors.

```
$ ebook-convert --version
..ebook-convert-wrapped-wrapped (calibre 5.42.0)
Created by: Kovid Goyal <kovid@kovidgoyal.net>
```

I have also tried pandoc, following both https://askubuntu.com/a/798129/

```
$ pandoc -f epub -t pdf /tmp/1.epub -o 1.pdf
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character − (U+2212)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.12696 ...lationship between two things (from −
```

and https://askubuntu.com/a/954582/

```
$ pandoc -s -t latex --toc --chapters --latex-engine=lualatex /tmp/1.epub -o 1.pdf
--chapters has been removed. Use --top-level-division=chapter instead.
--latex-engine has been removed.  Use --pdf-engine instead.
Try pandoc --help for more information.

$ pandoc -s -t latex --toc --top-level-division=chapter --pdf-engine=lualatex /tmp/1.epub -o 1.pdf
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.15624 \end{figure}}
```

Mine is:

```
$ pandoc --version
pandoc 2.17.1.1
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.22.2, texmath 0.12.4, skylighting 0.12.3,
citeproc 0.6.0.1, ipynb 0.2
User data directory: /home/t/.local/share/pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2022 John MacFarlane. Web:  https://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is no
warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.
```

Have I used both tools correctly? How would you convert the epub file to pdf?

Comment: So the input file converted (with multiple *warning* messages) via both gui and command line of Calibre 6.15.1.

Comment: thanks, @andrew.46. is it because I haven't updated Calibre since its 5.42 [03 May, 2022]?

Comment: Could be, you may have to follow Kovid's binary [Linux install](https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux) directions...

Comment: Newer version worked?

Comment: I can't install the newer version right now.

Comment: Do you have the licence to provide this ebook publicly? If not, then please delete the link, although then the question may become unanswerable because the issue indeed may be with the file.

Comment: Sigh... I don't know anything about ?US copyright law but I have removed the link to be sure...

Comment: @andrew.46 thanks. Apology for that concern, and thanks for removing the link. I still haven't found a way to upgrade my Calibre.  I was wondering if you are willing to help me again convert [a epub](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3361630500e7f21be86c51cc78285e7920231026170857/2fd538b227b66b08b4910e0e4d9e0c5e20231026170858/73e46d?trk=TRN_TDL_01&utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_01&utm_medium=email&utm_source=sendgrid) to pdf?  My archaic Calibre misses some articles in the pdf file it generates