# How do I convert epub to mobi using calibre?

Tags: format-conversion, calibre

How do I convert epub to mobi using Calibre for this?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Yes, Calibre package contains a script called [`ebook-convert`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ebook-convert.1) to convert ebooks between formats. You can install Calibre with

```
sudo apt-get install calibre
```

then

```
ebook-convert "book.epub" "book.mobi"
```

NB: Other formats are supported, too:

```
ebook-convert "book.azw3" "book.pdf"
```

Comment: FWIW, the quotes aren't strictly necessary.

Comment: To get an epub->pdf conversion to run, I had to make have `xvfb` installed and then run the `ebook-convert` command using:  `xvfb-run ebook-convert book.epub book.pdf`

Comment: I've figured out another way to use `ebook-convert` on a headless/server machine, without having to install Qt/X11 dependencies: https://askubuntu.com/a/1453851/182054

Answer (score 19):

I found [a script](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2085148) for batch conversion:

```
for book in *.epub; do echo "Converting $book"; ebook-convert "$book" "$(basename "$book" .epub).mobi"; done
```

It works good for me, but the process is pretty slow.

Answer (score 4):

Install calibre. Works with any arbitrary folder depth.

```
find . -name '*.epub' -type f -exec bash -c 'ebook-convert "$0" "${0%.epub}.mobi" --prefer-author-sort --output-profile=kindle --linearize-tables --smarten-punctuation --enable-heuristics' {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this without installing Calibre. This would be really handy on a Chromebook, for example. There is a free, online site called [EPUB Converter](http://www.epubconverter.com/epub-to-mobi-converter/) that will let you upload the `epub` and it lets you then download the `mobi` equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Calibre for epub to mobi conversion. They declare mobi as supported output format in their [FAQ](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#ebook-format-conversion).

I don’t think there’s anything Ubuntu-specific in the question, so it would probably belong somewhere else.

Comment: I think this question is relevant because I wasn't aware that Calibre was available for Ubuntu. For some reason I thought it was like Scrivener and Windows/Mac only.

Answer (score 1):

As of November 2021. I had to run the command using `sudo`.

E.g

```
sudo ebook-convert book.epub book.mobi
```

I didn't need the quotes, but you can use them if your file name has spaces. E.g:

`sudo ebook-convert "book one.epub" "book one.mobi"`

Everything else works as described in the accepted answer above.